# I can't get wkhtmltopdf to generate a PDF if there are broken images in the HTML

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf

Using WKHTMLTOPDF to generate PDF's and but it won't generate a PDF for me if there is a broken image on the HTML page I am generating the PDF from.

Here are the arguments I am using:

```
string arguments = "--print-media-type --footer-right [page]/[topage] ";
```

Is there a way to get it to ignore these broken images and generate a PDF anyways?

FYI I am pulling HTML in from webpages, so I cannot control if there are broken images or not.